# Google play store display a error "device is not compitable" when we install the app from play store

Tags: android

I do not find out the reason behind the error.And after surfing, most of the places give a suggestion "clear the Google Play Services data" but no have another alternative to handle them.please tell me the region and solutions to solve the Error.

Update

the reason behind the issue is few hardware does not support the devices (like.. camera: autofocus user feature ) so set require = "false" 
example in Manifest file :--

> Blockquote

uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false"

> Blockquote

it resolve the issue

Comment: - that's indicates you have set min sdk version in your build.gradle file of app.
- your device must have lower version than your min sdk version of app.

Comment: but In-app min SDK is  15  but an error occurs in  mobile that has android version 5.1

Comment: have you imported project from eclipse?

Comment: No, the framework used for that is  "Android Studio"

Comment: This might help you https://forums.androidcentral.com/optimus-elite-rooting-roms-hacks/224408-device-not-compatible.html